# Textarea sizes are change with the browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In my code I created textareas for get input, then after run the code it show correctly in Google chrome web browser. But when I run with the Firefox, the text area height had increased.

```
<td style="height:15px;width:15px">1</td>
<td><textarea class="form-control" id="spec1" name="date" type="text" rows="1.5" cols="30"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea class="form-control" id="minimum1" name="date" type="text" rows="1.5" cols="30"></textarea></td>
<td style="height:15px;width:15px"><input id="mandotory1"  name="date" type="checkbox" style="margin-Left:50px;margin-Top:10px;width: 15px;height: 15px;"/></td>
```

Google Chrome

[image: Chrome]

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Comment: Set the height of the textarea in CSS. `rows` and `cols` application can be inconsistent based on default font size.

Comment: To add to @RoryMcCrossan the `rows` and `cols` attributes have always been a bit of a guess at the size, they are more a suggestion, and as you've found out, is subject () to the browser vendors' interpretation.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. my Problem has solved. appreciate your help.